# AndroidのTEXTファイル読み込み(BufferedInputStreamの引数でエラー)

Tags: java, android

Androidでテキストファイルを読み込もうとしています。
BufferedInputStreamのところで、エラーがで出てしまいます。

内容はBufferedInputStreamの引数としてInputStreamが要求されているのに、InputStramReaderが渡されている
というものです。

> Required type:InputStream
> Provided type:InputStreamReader

調べたところ、InputStreamはabstractクラスでInputStreamReaderに継承されているので問題ない気がするのです。。
また、処理としても、FileInputStreamでバイトとして読み込み、InputStreamReaderでバイトをテキストにして
BufferedInputStreamで行末までのバッファにすると自分は理解したのですが。。。

ネット上のコードを見に行ったところ、同じようにBufferedInputStreamの引数にInputStreamReaderを渡していました。。
何故にエラーとなってしまうでしょうか。

```
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        try {

            FileInputStream infs = openFileInput(aaa.txt);
            BufferedInputStream bfin = new BufferedInputStream( new InputStreamReader(infs));

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: すみません。自己解決しました。BufferedInputStreamではなくてBufferedReaderで受取でした。申し訳ありません

Answer (score 1):

コメントにて解決済みです。
原因はBufferedInputStreamとBufferedReaderの勘違いです・・・